# php if statement to check if current datetime is between 2 datetime columns

Tags: php, datetime

PostQopen and PostQClose are datetime columns.
I need a php if statement to check if the current datetime is between the PostQopen and PostQClose columns.

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if($rows['PostQopen'] >= '$now' && $rows['PostQClose'] < '$now' ){

echo "TRUE";

} else { 

echo "FALSE";

};
```

Comment: You don't need single quotes around the '$now' - try removing it and seeing if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 12):

Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

```
$now = new DateTime("now");
$PostQopen = new DateTime($rows['PostQopen']);
$PostQClose = new DateTime($rows['PostQClose']);

if($PostQopen >= $now && $PostQClose <=$now){
 // do ur stuff
}
```

Comment: THIS WORKED FOR ME.
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$PostQopen = $rows['PostQopen'];
$PostQClose = $rows['PostQClose'];

if($now >= $PostQopen && $now < $PostQClose){ echo "TRUE"; };

Comment: well u should avoid using strtotime() and use DateTime instead since strtotime() has many limitations and does not work in many cases.

Comment: The above solution is not between it's actually not between.

Answer (score 1):

Remove single quotes from $now and use `strtotime()`. Still without `strtotime()`, the code will work since you can `compare time` if it is in `datetime format`.

```
if(strtotime($rows['PostQopen']) >= strtotime($now) && strtotime($rows['PostQClose']) < strtotime($now) )
{
   echo "TRUE";
} 
else
{ 
   echo "FALSE";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if(strtotime($rows['PostQopen']) >= strtotime('$now') && strtotime($rows['PostQClose']) < strtotime('$now') ){

echo "TRUE";

} else { 

echo "FALSE";

};
```

Check if this works, strtotime converts given time into millisecond format, It should work

Answer (score 1):

Function to find out between using `DateTime` is here:

```
function dateIsBetween($from, $to, $date="now") {
    $date = new \DateTime($date);
    $from= new \DateTime($from);
    $to = new \DateTime($to);
    if ($date >= $from && $date <= $to) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using the function

```
dateIsBetween('2016-02-24', '2016-02-26', '2016-02-25'); //would return true
dateIsBetween('2016-02-24', '2016-02-26', 'now'); //would return true if the current date would be between specified to, from
dateIsBetween('2016-02-24', '2016-02-26'); //would return true if the current date would be between specified to, from
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of native date() function, better using DateTime object, here is example of your case if

**NOW() BETWEEN PostQopen AND PostQclose**

```
$now = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$DateRange = array(
    'PostQopen'     => new DateTime($rows['PostQopen']),
    'PostQClose'    => new DateTime($rows['PostQClose']),
);
if (($DateRange['PostQopen'] <= $now) && ($DateRange['PostQClose'] > $now)) {
    echo "TRUE";
} else {
    echo "FALSE";
}
```